# What does |= (single pipe equal) and &=(single ampersand equal) mean

Tags: c#, operators, bitwise-operators

In below lines:

```
//Folder.Attributes = FileAttributes.Directory | FileAttributes.Hidden | FileAttributes.System | FileAttributes.ReadOnly;
Folder.Attributes |= FileAttributes.Directory | FileAttributes.Hidden | FileAttributes.System | FileAttributes.ReadOnly;


Folder.Attributes |= ~FileAttributes.System;
Folder.Attributes &= ~FileAttributes.System;
```

What does `|=` (single pipe equal) and `&=` (single ampersand equal) mean in C#?

I want to remove system attribute with keeping the others...

Answer (score 213, accepted):

They're [*compound assignment*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/bitwise-and-shift-operators#compound-assignment) operators, translating (very loosely)

```
x |= y;
```

into

```
x = x | y;
```

and the same for `&`. There's a bit more detail in a few cases regarding an implicit cast, and the target variable is only evaluated once, but that's basically the gist of it.

In terms of the non-compound operators, [`&` is a bitwise "AND"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/bitwise-and-shift-operators#logical-and-operator-) and [`|` is a bitwise "OR"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/bitwise-and-shift-operators#logical-exclusive-or-operator-).

EDIT: In this case you want `Folder.Attributes &= ~FileAttributes.System`. To understand why:

- `~FileAttributes.System` means "all attributes *except* `System`" (`~` is a bitwise-NOT)
- `&` means "the result is all the attributes which occur on both sides of the operand"

So it's basically acting as a mask - *only* retain those attributes which appear in ("everything except System"). In general:

- `|=` will only ever *add* bits to the target
- `&=` will only ever *remove* bits from the target

Comment: `x = x | (y);` is a better way to describe it because `x |= y + z;` is not the same as `x = x | y + z;`

Comment: thanks for answers / but for my purpose(removing system attribute) which one should i use (|= or &=)?

Comment: @LostLord: `Folder.Attributes &= ~FileAttributes.System;`

Comment: Side note: `|=` and `&=` can be used as logical operators as well as bitwise operators.

Answer (score 44):

- `|` is [bitwise or](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation)
- `&` is [bitwise and](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation)

`a |= b` is equivalent to `a = a | b` except that `a` is evaluated only once
`a &= b` is equivalent to `a = a & b` except that `a` is evaluated only once

In order to remove the System bit without changing other bits, use

```
Folder.Attributes &= ~FileAttributes.System;
```

`~` is bitwise negation. You will thus set all bits to 1 except the System bit. `and`-ing it with the mask will set System to 0 and leave all other bits intact because `0 & x = 0` and `1 & x = x` for any `x`

Comment: What does it mean that `a` is only evaluated once? Why would it be evaluated more times than that?

Comment: @silkfire This is called short-circuit evaluation, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation

Comment: @Polluks So basically `a |= b` actually means `a = a || b`?

Comment: @silkfire Yep but don't interchange one pipe and two pipes.

Comment: @Polluks: I fail to understand your comment about one and two pipes - I think using two pipes instead of one was silkfire's entire point in that [last comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6942477#comment95263986_6942502). Also, I am not convinced the statement "except that `a` is evaluated only once` does indeed refer to short-circuit evaluation, as short-circuit evaluation does not change the evaluation of the *first* operand ( `a` ), but might skip the evaluation of the *second* operand ( `b` ).

Comment: @silkfire it means a "not lazy" ||, i.e. both parts of the expression are always calculated, whereas 2nd part of a standard "lazy" || may not be calculated.

Answer (score 3):

> I want to remove system attribute with keeping the others..

You can do this like so:

```
Folder.Attributes ^= FileAttributes.System;
```

Comment: I think you want to use a XOR instead of an AND for this.

Comment: a bit confused / ~is necessary or not

Comment: @LostLord The two methods are analogous as far as I'm aware

Comment: @ChrisS `^= bit` will set the bit if it was not already set, `&= ~bit` does not set it.

Comment: you definitely don't want to use an xor.  That would put it back if it was gone.