# checkbox does not working as expected

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have three checkboxes in my form. The problem is that when I check all three, I only received one checkbox. how can I fix this?

my code:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ConfigOptions itemToSave = 0;

        if (autoCapsNames.Checked)
        {
            itemToSave |= ConfigOptions.AutoCapsStr;
        }

        if (autoSort.Checked)
        {
            itemToSave |= ConfigOptions.IntantOrganization;
        }

        if (showLinesNumbers.Checked)
        {
            itemToSave |= ConfigOptions.ShowLinesNumber;
        }


        SaveConfigs(itemToSave);


    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Please paste ConfigOptions code as well. SaveConfigs method code may be helpful as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The previous answer should solve your issue, but it changes the way you handle the data. 
If you want to use bitwise OR method (as you are doing now), make sure you have correctly defined `ConfigOptions`. Values assigned to `ConfigOptions.AutoCapsStr`, `ConfigOptions.IntantOrganization` and `ConfigOptions.ShowLinesNumber` should be chosen in such a way to define the values you set in a unique way.

If `ConfigOptions` is an `enum`, you can try to define it like this:

```
enum ConfigOptions
{
    AutoCapsStr = 1, 
    IntantOrganization = 2, 
    ShowLinesNumber = 4
}
```

Then, you can use it inside your `SaveConfigs` method (or in your loading method, if you just save the numeric value) to test values set like this:

```
if (itemToSave & ConfigOptions.AutoCapsStr != 0)
{
    //ConfigOptions.AutoCapsStr is set, so do appropriate things here
}
```

Comment: Thanks for +1 :). Using OR this way is not very intuitive, but can be helpful sometimes. I'm glad the information is useful for You :).

Comment: Apparently it's a good idea to use the `FlagsAttribute` on this type of enum. http://stackoverflow.com/a/8480/124069

Comment: Also, bit shifting can be useful in this as well, so that you don't have to deal with the calculations. `enum ConfigOptions{AutoCapsStr = 1 << 0, IntantOrganization 1 << 1, ShowLinesNumber 1 << 2}`

Answer (score 0):

Your code might only be setting the `itemToSave` once. If all your checkboxes are checked, you could end up only saving `showLineNumbers` since you're overwriting itemToSave through every if statement.

You might to want to change your approach a little. You could

1. `SaveConfigs(itemToSave);` **inside** each `if` statement, thereby saving each config option individually.
2. Store each `itemToSave` inside a `List<T>`, and loop through the list, saving what you need at the end.

Here's a quick and dirty approach to get you started

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<ConfigOptions> itemsToSave = default(List<ConfigOptions>);

    if (autoCapsNames.Checked)
    {
        itemsToSave.Add(ConfigOptions.AutoCapsStr);
    }

    if (autoSort.Checked)
    {
        itemsToSave.Add(ConfigOptions.IntantOrganization);
    }

    if (showLinesNumbers.Checked)
    {
        itemsToSave.Add(ConfigOptions.ShowLinesNumber);
    }

    SaveConfigs(itemsToSave); // You're passing the list, and parsing it within the SaveConfigs method.
}
```

Alternatively if you're going to use `int`'s in a bitwise calculation, please see @Lucas's answer. I've personally never done it that way, but he has a great point. (I've learned something today).

Comment: He may be not overwriting the itemToSave variable, because he's using |=, not =. It should work if the ConfigOptions is defined correctly.

Comment: I'm not as well versed in C# as I should be, but doesn't `|=` translate into `itemToSave = itemToSave [OR] newItemToSave`? It appears to me that he wants [AND], yet the `|&` would be used to remove (and not add). /re [Jon Skeet](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6942494/124069)

Comment: Yes, it does translate to OR. It's a logical OR, so he cumulatively adds other values by bitwise ORing them i.e.: int i = 0; i|=2; i|=8; gives you i == 10 as a result. You can set selected bits this way and tread reads them to see which options were chosen.

Comment: @ChaseFlorell No, Lucas is right. It depends of the defintion of ConfigOptions.

Comment: @Lucas I follow you now! That would make a good alternative answer to this question.