# What does the |= Operator mean?

Tags: c#

In some code i found this `|=` operator used to return a `uint` but i can find something about it on the internet and i wanna understand how it works and what are the return values in this case.

```
public uint Mask
{
    get
    {
        uint num = 0;
        if (_0)
            num |= 1U;
        if (_1)
            num |= 2U;
        if (_2)
            num |= 4U;
        return num;
    }
}
```

a detailed answer will be much appreciated.

Comment: It is simply `num = num | x;`

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5f1zzaw.aspx perhaps this link will help

Comment: [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/h5f1zzaw.aspx) on the ```|=``` operator

Comment: It's the binary OR combined with an assignment. Like += or -=.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what does |= (single pipe equal) and &=(single ampersand equal) mean](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6942477/what-does-single-pipe-equal-and-single-ampersand-equal-mean)

Comment: thanks guys but i really did a google search and nothing came up. sorry if it is a duplicate.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You know how `x += 1` means `x = x + 1`, well `x |= 1` means `x = x | 1`.  Of course `|` means bitwise OR.

Comment: i wasn't expecting that, what a shame :D. thanks for your answer dude.